Two structurally identical GCloud Functions behaves differently
This function doesn't work:
exports.createNotificationChat = onDocumentWritten(
    "tiutiu/env/{environment}/contacts/{userId}/{contactId}/messages/{messageId}",
    (event) => {
      console.log(`Epaa Data  ${event.data.after.ref.path}`);
    });

Output of createNotificationChat on Gcloud console
But this other function is working well
exports.sacanagem = onDocumentWritten(
    "tiutiu/env/{sacanagem}/anything/{anything}/{porra}/nenhuma/{doc}",
    (event) => {
      console.log(`Epaa sacanagem viu vey ${event.data.after.ref.path}`);
    });

Output of sacanagem on Gcloud console
I expected that they both show the console.log content, but is not what is happening. Why?
The path on Firestore that should trigger the function has the same depth for both functions.

Are you sure the path is correct?

Yes, I am. As I'm populating the Firestore via a mobile app, and the 2nd gen of Functions is still at the beginning, plus it is not mandatory to migrate, I rolled back to the first gen and all things are on track again.
